# Mouse jumps around in Virtualbox Windows 3.1

Tags: virtualbox, windows-3.1

When I use Windows 3.1 in Virtualbox, my mouse jumps up and down when I move the mouse up and down. I could be at the bottom of the screen and I move my mouse down and it jumps to the top. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I'm suspecting older/non existent mouse drivers are giving you issues. What kind of mouse are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox does not [support](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) Windows 3.1.  In a *supported* OS, you could install the Guest Addition tools to install the video, mouse, etc drivers.

The good news is, it would appear you can run Windows 3.1 in [DosBox](http://www.sierrahelp.com/Utilities/Emulators/DOSBox/3x_install.html).

Answer (score -3):

It due to problems in the 32/16 bit conversion, you can't do anything about it.

Comment: [Citation needed](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wikipedian_protester.png) - While your theory is interesting and plausible, without more information, its impossible to prove whether you are right or wrong